# Northwind SQL total orders per customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I've added a column `TotalOrders` to the `Customers` table.

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD TotalOrders INT NULL
```

I'm trying to find the total number of orders per customer and add that value to this column, however i can't figure out what do i need to sum exactly

```
INSERT INTO customers (TotalOrders) SELECT SUM(...)
```

Comment: You might not want to add a total orders column.  Rather, this column can be computed at the time you query the table.

Comment: I'm afraid this was given as a task, and it stated specifically to create the column and then add values to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using an *update* here.  You can aggregate the total number of orders per customer in the `orders` table, and then update the `customers` table with this information.

```
UPDATE t1
SET TotalOrders = t2.TotalOrders
FROM customers t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS TotalOrders
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
) t2
    ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO customers (TotalOrders) 
VALUES(SELECT SUM(Orders.Total)  
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerId=
Customer.Id Group By  Customer.Id) WHERE Customer.Id =Orders.CustomerId
```

Comment: Mind explaining what's `Orders.Total` ?

Comment: I'm sorry about the field names, I don't have northwind installed and don't remember the names, but I means the general total in Order table. If Total don't exist you need to multiply price x quantity for each Order Item