# Adventure Works 2014 SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, adventureworks

I am writing a SQL query using Adventure Works 2014 database.

I want to show all customers and how many orders each customers have.

I tried to write each select statement by itself (see below), but I'd like to be able to combine both queries into one.

```
select  s.CustomerID ,p.FirstName +' '+p.LastName as Name 
from Sales.Customer s,Person.Person p 
where s.CustomerID=p.BusinessEntityID
order by s.CustomerID


select CustomerID ,count(SalesOrderID) as OrdersCount
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by CustomerID
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Northwind SQL total orders per customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084941/northwind-sql-total-orders-per-customer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT s.CustomerID ,
        p.FirstName +' '+p.LastName as Name,
        count(SalesOrderID)
 FROM Sales.Customer s
 JOIN Person.Person p 
   ON s.CustomerID=p.BusinessEntityID
 LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader so
   ON s.Customer_ID = so.Customer_ID  
 GROUP BY s.CustomerID ,
        p.FirstName +' '+p.LastName as Name 
 order by s.CustomerID
```

Comment: thank you for answering , the problem is there are many customers did not make any orders so they do not appear with this query

Comment: @GeorgeKouki Try a `left join`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Click here for the Query its an image]

I added CONCAT just as something new for u probably. Anyways the OVER(PARTITION BY *column_name*) clause was used as a replacement for GROUP BY since you are printing more columns than what a GROUP BY clause would allow.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do not add code (in this case the full query) as images. This makes it impossible to copy it or make edits in your post directly :)

Answer (score 0):

Table Sales.Customer
References:Person.Person (PersonID -> BusinessEntityID)

```
SELECT s.CustomerID 
        ,p.FirstName +' '+p.LastName as Name
        ,COUNT(so.SalesOrderDetailID)
 FROM Sales.Customer s
 JOIN Person.Person p 
   ON s.PersonID=p.BusinessEntityID
 LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader h 
   ON h.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail so
   ON so.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
 GROUP BY s.CustomerID ,
        p.FirstName +' '+p.LastName
 order by s.CustomerID
```